# $\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le\frac{p}{p-1}\lVert f\rVert_{L^{p}(0,\infty)}$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty,$show that 
$$\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le\frac{p}{p-1}\lVert f\rVert_{L^{p}(0,\infty)}$$

Here is my attempt :

\begin{align}
\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}&\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{|f(t)|^{p}}{x^{p}}~dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(|f(t)|^{p}\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{p}}~dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(|f(t)|^{p}\frac{t^{1-p}}{p-1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt
\end{align}

,where the first I used minkowski inequality of integral form.

Then I stuck with it . But I got a hint to apply the convolution with some function .

Is there anybody that can show more details ? Thanks for considering my request .